# ejb3 access in out of container way

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I dive in ejb in action code example and stuck with access to ejb3 out of jboss container.
I'm having 2 session beans deployed on jboss 6.1.0 and i see from server log: ebj beans are bound to global jndi(java:global/?). So i have running client and it creates initialcontext with jndi.properties file:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=127.0.0.1:1098
```

My client code looks like:
    ...
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    Object stub = context.lookup("chapter2/PlaceOrderBean/remote");
    ...
I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProxyFactory not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399)
```

I think jboss6 supports rmi and iiop-rmi protocol for remote ejbs. But i only experience in websphere 10. Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i found the answer for myself.
it might be helpful for someone.
First i took jboss community version and last time i did example with production version: jboss 5.1.0 GA . Bless God! it's working perfect.